# Routing with subdomain or path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

My app has a section of the site that I would like to be accessed via the root domain and a subdomain.

Fo example, I have some routes set up with the format of:

```
match 'dashboard' => 'dashboard/home#index', :as => :dashboard_home
match 'dashboard/tasks' => 'dashboard/tasks#index', :as => :dashboard_tasks
```

These match mydomain.com/dashboard and mydomain.com/dashboard/tasks, respectively.

I would like to also match these routes as dashboard.mydomain.com and dashboard.mydomain.com/tasks.  Is there a way to do this without having to duplicate all the route entries?